# auto-complete (Intellisense) in Excel sheet created using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have used `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace to create excel sheets using `C#`. I want to have the auto-complete or Intellisense feature for a column in it. A particular column should have only two values in it. The values are BUS and TRAIN. When the user types B in any cell of that column; the text in the cell should get changed to BUS and when the user types T, the text should get changed to TRAIN.

I researched and found out there is a method called `AutoComplete`. But it looks for text from predefined list. How do I specify the predefined list?

any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call it as `Range.AutoComplete(string)`, where the Range contains [BUS, TRAIN] or the like.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @HaloWebMaster. Can you please elaborate how to add the strings `[BUS,TRAIN]` to `Range`.

Comment: just put them on the spreadsheet somewhere and use `app.get_Range("A1:H10")` where app is an Excel.Application object

Comment: The thing is.. excel sheet created will be empty initially .. so i cannot use the `app.get_Range()` . Is there any way to set the list of strings for a column.

Comment: see this blog post for inserting an array into a Range programatically: http://dotnetdud.blogspot.com/2008/11/insert-array-to-excel-range-using-vsto.html